# how do i center strings in java

Tags: java, string

sorry this is a jumbled mess of code but i would like my program to output something like this

[image: example of what i want]

i can get close to it but either the text is inside of the stars and it isnt centered or its centered and the  three stars in the right middle are moved here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String msg;
        int width = 54;
        Scanner pipe = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print ("Enter a message to for a header: ");
        msg = pipe.next();
        int spaceTaken = width - msg.length();
        int center = (spaceTaken - msg.length()) / 2;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
            for (int x = 1; x <= 60; x++) {
                System.out.print ("*");
            }
            System.out.println ();
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
            for (int x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {
                System.out.print ("*");
            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
            for (int x = 1; x <= center + msg.length(); x++) {
                System.out.print (" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.format ("%" + msg.length() + "s", msg);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
            for (int x = 1; x <= center - (msg.length() / 2); x++) {
                System.out.print (" ");
            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
            for (int x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {
                System.out.print ("*");
            }
            System.out.println ();
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
            for (int x = 1; x <= 60; x++) {
                System.out.print ("*");
            }
            System.out.println ();
        } 
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you want the length of the outer star line to be a constant or is it fine if it changes a bit?

Comment: @mettleap i would like it to be 60 stars on the top and bottom so consistent and 3 on the sides also thank you for taking a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there all lots of libraries that will do it, but just as an exercise - the function below will generate a line like `***   message   ***` (not perfect though):

```
public String center(String message, int length, int sides, char border) {
    if(message.length() + 2*sides > length) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot center " + message + " within " + length + 
                                        "characters");
    }   
    int chars = message.length() + 2*sides;
    int gap = (length - chars)/2;
    int extra = (length - chars) % 2;
    StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < sides; i++) {
        line.append(border);
    }   
    for(int i = 0; i < gap; i++) {
        line.append(" "); 
    }   
    line.append(message);
    for(int i = 0; i < gap + extra; i++) {
        line.append(" "); 
    }   
    for(int i = 0; i < sides; i++) {
        line.append(border);
    }   
    return line.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a lot of problemns in your solution.

Sorry, I did not understand your logic.

But I will give some tips for you undestand.

1) Do not use  `for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {...}` this is not necessary.

2) This is most important, you have to split the *Left* and *Right* Spaces, and know that some left or right side can have an extra start.

3) Divide your problems in methods, you should have a method to *getMessage* of console, a method to count all the starts, and get the message in the center.

4) Your class name should start with uppercase (its the convention).

5) Prefer `StringBuilder` than `String`, it's efficient.

I've tried to make it as simple as possible for you to understand:

....

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    String msg;
    int width = 60;
    Scanner pipe = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a message to for a header: ");
    msg = pipe.next();
    StringBuilder asterisk = new StringBuilder(width);
    for (int x = 1; x <= 60; x++) {
        asterisk.append("*");
    }
    int qntSpaceBlank = (width - msg.length() - 6);

    int qtdSpaceLeft;
    int qtdSpaceRigth;
    if (qntSpaceBlank % 2 == 0) {
        qtdSpaceLeft = qntSpaceBlank / 2;
        qtdSpaceRigth = qntSpaceBlank / 2;
    } else {
        qtdSpaceLeft = qntSpaceBlank / 2;
        qtdSpaceRigth = qntSpaceBlank/2 + 1;
    }
    StringBuilder spaceBlankLeft = new StringBuilder(qtdSpaceLeft);
    StringBuilder spaceBlankRight = new StringBuilder(qtdSpaceRigth);

    for (int i = 1; i <= qtdSpaceLeft; i++) {
        spaceBlankLeft.append(" ");
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= qtdSpaceRigth; i++) {
        spaceBlankRight.append(" ");
    }
    StringBuilder textCenter = new StringBuilder(width);
    textCenter.append("***")
            .append(spaceBlankLeft)
            .append(msg)
            .append(spaceBlankRight)
            .append("***");

    System.out.println(asterisk);
    System.out.println(textCenter);
    System.out.println(asterisk);
}
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas one can use to print the required output. Please note that these are "tools" - one can use these to write a correct(ed) program. This has some free-text program logic and a picture to help "see" the problem.

*Program logic:*

```
Initial:
Total length = 60
Length of three stars = 3
Message length allowed = (Total length) - (Length of three stars * 2)
Accept/Enter Message string
Message length = Input string length
If Message length is zero  or greater than Message length allowed
    Cannot print - abort program.

Begin printing:
Print the beginning sixty stars
Print the first 3 stars
Starting length = (Total length / 2) - (Length of three stars) - (Message length / 2)
Print spaces upto the Starting length
Print the Message string
Ending length = Starting length
If message length is odd number
    Ending length = Starting length - 1
Print spaces upto the Ending length
Print the last 3 stars
Print the end sixty stars
End printing.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The center calculation is incorrect, in your case it's always static. Following is the output of your code, notice how the string start point is always static:

```
************************************************************
***                           a                          ***
************************************************************
************************************************************
***                           aa                        ***
************************************************************
************************************************************
***                           aaa                       ***
************************************************************
```

The center of the string does not change as per string length. Make following code changes(your code is commented):

1. Center calculation logic:

`//int center = (spaceTaken - msg.length()) / 2;
int center = (width - msg.length()) / 2;`

2. Suffix spaces till center:

`//for (int x = 1; x <= center + msg.length(); x++) {
for (int x = 1; x <= center; x++) {`

3. Prefix remaining spaces:

`//for (int x = 1; x <= center - (msg.length() / 2); x++) {
for (int x = 1; x <= center; x++) {`

4. For odd length strings, add an extra space. After prefixing spaces and before printing end `"*"`, add following code:

`if(  msg.length() % 2 > 0 )
            System.out.print (" ");`

Following is the output after code change, notice how the string start point changes:

```
************************************************************
***                          a                           ***
************************************************************
************************************************************
***                          aa                          ***
************************************************************
************************************************************
***                         aaa                          ***
************************************************************
```

Finally, your code can be improved for re-usability, readability and manageability. To start with, consider pushing repeat code to a method. For instance, for printing borders, you could create a `printBorder()`. Create a separate method(taking required parameters) which returns a string after its centered.